# Transpose of a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

In my database I have a table, which has a column A and the respective values are:

```
A
--
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there any way that I can convert the table into

```
A|1|2|3|4|5|
```

I tried using the `PIVOT` keyword but I'm not able to get the result.

Comment: what did you try with the `PIVOT` keyword and what did you get?

Comment: @S. Vikneshwar - Do you know how many columns you want in the result?  That is, do you always want 6 columns in the result?  Or do you want the number of columns to vary based on the number of rows in the table?

Comment: Not sure if this helps you
inline `select * 
    from (
        select  'a' colname, 1 as a from dual
    ) **tab**
    pivot (
    max(a)
    for a in ( 1,2,3,4,5,6) 
    )`

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temp2(a integer);
insert into temp2 values(1);
insert into temp2 values(2);
insert into temp2 values(3);
insert into temp2 values(4);
```

Your requirement is not clear,but i tried this with `UNPIVOT`.I dnt know how many columns you want in your result,but i am sure this will give you the hint on which way you need to proceed.

```
SELECT
  "Key",
  wm_concat(value)
FROM Temp2
UNPIVOT (
  value FOR "Key" IN (a)
)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Key     WM_CONCAT(VALUE)
--------------------------
A           1,2,4,3
```

If you remove the wm_concat function then it will give the below output.

```
 Key    VALUE
--------------------
 A      1
 A      2
 A      4
 A      3
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many columns to expect, then maybe use [XMLAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm).
It won't give you columns but a xml element for every row. Afterwards you can extract each element to a column.
look at this example:

```
with t as (select xmlagg(xmlelement("E", a)) a_xml from your_table)
select rtrim(extract(a_xml, 'E[1]/text()')),
       rtrim(extract(a_xml, 'E[2]/text()')),
       rtrim(extract(a_xml, 'E[3]/text()')),
       rtrim(extract(a_xml, 'E[4]/text()')),
       rtrim(extract(a_xml, 'E[5]/text()'))
from t
```